# Grails Pessimistic Lockdown doesn't work (in my case)

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

in Greach 2.0, Burt Beckwith talked about **Pessimistic Lockdown**.

I'm trying to setup Pessimistic Lockdown in my grails application but it doesn't work.

I've written in my Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
```

and my controller is:

```
class LibreController {
   def index = {
      render 'Forbidden access because there isn\'t rule'
   }
}
```

and typing in my navigator "http: // local /PruebaSeguridad /libre" I can read the message *"Forbidden access because there isn't rule"* without any authentication.

I'm not sure if I understood how Pessimistic Lockdown works or i'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: of course i've read the documentation in http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html and I've googled it, but ...

Comment: Works for me. It shouldn't be necessary, but did you already run the `s2-quickstart` script? Also - what version of Grails are you using?

Comment: Hi Burt, yes I've run s2-quickstart and I'm using Grails 2.1.1 and plugin spring security core 1.2.7.3. Also, I'm using plugin kickstart-with-bootstrap 0.8.9, but I supose this doesn't mind

Comment: should I configurate allowedMethods in controller or is it not need?

Comment: You should try it without the kickstart-with-bootstrap plugin to see if that is affecting things. `allowedMethods` isn't related to this - it determines which request type (GET/POST/etc) is allowed for each method.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Initially I installed the *kickstart-with-bootstrap* plugin after *spring-security-core* and (I suppose) it broke something. I reinstalled kickstart-with-bootstrap after installing spring-security-core plugin and it works perfectly.

thank you very much